# How to hide non-existents members in dimension?

Tags: olap, mondrian, rolap

I have two dimensions: Mall, Gallery. First mall have gallery #1-3, second mall have gallery #4. How to hide gallery #4 for first mall and gallery #1-3 for second mall?[image: jpivot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fault, OLAP don't work like i except. I can hide all null cells only.